# Laravel Passport Authroziation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

I have an application which works with Laravel and VueJs. Also i have a VK-bot. Bot and Vue use the same API-routes.

For bot i use oauth access token with next headers

> Accept : application/json, Authorization: Bearer my_token_code

bot works well.

For VueJs i use X-CSRF-TOKEN. When i try send requests from vue i get an error

> Unauthenticated.

my routes

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');

    Route::post('/replace/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceImage');

    Route::get('/replaceall/', 'CompgenApiController@replaceAllImages');

    Route::get('/collage/', 'CompgenApiController@collage'); //@todo replace to POST

    Route::get('/generate/', 'CompgenApiController@generate');

    Route::post('/upload/', 'CompgenApiController@userUpload');

    Route::post('/reupload/', 'CompgenApiController@moderationReupload');

    Route::post('/feedback/', 'CompgenApiController@feedback');

});
```

my app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:1000,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

my app.js

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
};
```

Comment: A CSRF token is not an access token, it's for mitigating [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

Comment: okay, and how can i solve my problem?

Comment: You need to send an authorization token in the axios requests the same as  your with the bot. Add a request interceptor to axios and attach the token to every outbound request.

Comment: Here are examples of interceptors from the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

Comment: Yea, but in this case i will send auth token in request headers. Some intruders will be able this info to hack my application

Comment: How do you plan on authenticating? This is straight from the documentation: `When calling routes that are protected by Passport, your application's API consumers should specify their access token as a **Bearer token in the Authorization header** of their request`. [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#protecting-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your api guard provider to 'passport'? on config/auth.php

Comment: I see, (and sorry I meant on driver).
You shouldn't be sending any _Authorization Header_ when you are consuming your own API with js or vue. 
The `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken` middleware sends a cookie called laravel_token on every request which is your authenticated user.

Comment: but i already added  \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class